# Collecting an iterator of threads into a vector start the threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, iterator

The following snippet shows mapping an iterator into threads and collecting into a `Vec`

```
let workers = input
        .chunks(chunk_size)
        .map(|chunk| {
            let lines = chunk.iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
            thread::spawn(move || count_letters(&lines))
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Won't this start all threads running (up to the os creating them)? In other words, there is no real limit to how many threads will be created aside from the length of `input`.

Assuming this is true, if one wanted to do this pattern without instantiating all the threads upon `collect`, might one use another closure i.e. `thread::spawn(move || count_letters(&lines))` -> `|| thread::spawn(move || count_letters(&lines))` and would this be the rust style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Won't this start all threads running (up to the os creating them)?

Yes. Technically the `collect` is not even necessary here, a `for` would do.

> Assuming this is true, if one wanted to do this pattern without instantiating all the threads upon collect, might one use another closure

But then... why bother with the `spawn`, or the two closures? You can just put that where you'd call the outer closure.

> would this be the rust style?

The rust style would be to use [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/index.html), probably.

If you wanted to do that by hand, then the usual: create a queue (an mpmc channel of some sort, possibly bounded), spawn however many workers you have feeding from the queue, push all your work on the queue, then collect the results somehow.

Comment: This was not my code I just wanted to verify my suspicion as the problem the code is written to solve requires a limit on the number of worker threads. I did use a queue in my version. This was a practice problem so I'd say rayon was discouraged